# algorithm to use to find closest object on tile map

Tags: c#, algorithm, path-finding, closest

I have a game map represented as a tile map. Currently there are two types of objects that are present on the map, relevant to this problem: gatherable resources (trees, rocks, etc.) and buildings built by the player. Buildings are also connected by roads.

I have a problem figuring out an efficient algorithm that could do the following:

- find the closest resource to any relevant building (ie. find the closest tree to lumberjack/tree-gatherer)
- find the closest relevant building to any building (ie. find the closest storage to any sawmill)

I separated those two issues because the first one **does not** need roads, but the second one is supposed to **only** use roads.

So, the result of this should be a single path to a single object, that is the closest to the one I'm figuring it out from. The path is then used by a worker to gather the resource and bring it back, or let's say, to pick a resource from a sawmill and bring it to the closest storage.

I know how to get the closest path itself (A*, Djikstra or even Floyd-Warshall), but I'm not sure how to optimally proceed with multiples of those and getting the best/closest one, especially if it's going to be run very regularly and the map object collections (roads and buildings) is expected to be changing regularly as well.

I'm doing this in Unity3D/c# but I guess this is not really Unity3D-related issue.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Finding the geographical distance between two objects is a cheap (quick) operation - you can afford to perform that many times per game tick. Use it if the option is available.

Finding the shortest path by making use of terrain features such as roads, tracks etc. is a much more complex operation. As you already mentioned in your post the A* search algorithm is probably your best option for it, but it is quite slow.

But generally, you should **not need to run it too often** - just compute the path every X seconds (for some value of X), and make your worker spend the next few game ticks following this computed path, until you "refresh" it. The more precision you have, and more responsiveness to changes to the game environment (e.g. obstacles appearing in your path), the more CPU time you will use.

Try different amounts of precision, and find one that gives decent precision while not being too expensive in terms of CPU time. (The update interval depends purely on the number of calls you are expected to make. Calculating paths for 100 workers is obviously much harder than for 1.)

Comment: You're right. But following (and updating) a final path once I figure out which object is the closest, is a different issue. Figuring out the closest object is the problem. One lumberjack can have access to 100s of trees and finding a closest path to a single one of them is quite easy. But regularly checking/updating a list of all of them and picking the closest/shortest one, is what I'm after.

Comment: Assuming that you are using a set of waypoints (a grid, most likely?) you can just start from the worker's location and search for arbitrary trees. There's no need to search ALL the trees.

Once your search has found a tree, you know that the "optimal" path must be no longer than that path. So when searching other routes, you can immediately give up on a route if it exceeds that upper bound.

Comment: I'll probably end up using some kind of hierarchical pathfinding. First, I'd have to split the whole tilemap into smaller regions (let's say 8x8), and all tiles within a single region would be garanteed to be accessible to each other. So, in the end, getting the closest object would require finding it on the region level and then getting a path to it, restricted to the regions it needs to go through. I believe one of the algorithms that does this is HPA*.